# Waiting for transformation to complete?

Tags: c#, xslt

I have this code to transform XMl to HTML:

```
// Now perform the transformation
XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
transformer.Load(strTransformXSLPath, new XsltSettings { EnableDocumentFunction = true }, xmlResolver);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strScheduleHTMLPath))
{
    transformer.Transform(strScheduleXMLPath, argsList, sw);
}
```

How can I get it to wait for the file to HTML file to be ready before returning? I don't know if this code already guarantees that all writing to the HTML file is complete before return.

Comment: "guarantees that all writing to the HTML file is complete before return" why do you assume the opposite? There's nothing async here, so the transformation may take several minutes before any further line of code is executed.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I am not assume anything. I am asking the question. How can I ensure it has completed the save before I return? What steps must I take.

Comment: @Andrew There is no need for insurance. Transformation completes after Transform command, text written to file when StreamWriter is flushed. This happens on Dispose. This happens when you are past last bracket.

Comment: @eocron But, does that mean it has physically completed too? Ie. if I tru to use that HTML is is guaranteed to be ready to read from?

Comment: It is guaranteed at system level, either it is completed or you get an exception on Dispose/Write (OutOfMemory, AcccessException, ThreadAbortion, etc) which can be handled aproppriatelly. The same you get at any given point running any given app in most systems. If you chop your computer with an axe it is not guaranteed.

Comment: That is no different from demanding a guarantee that in `i++; MessageBox(i.ToString());` the `++` will be complete before the `MessageBox`.

Comment: It has cases where it is not guaranteed, for example if you use Dokan mapped drives (like google disk, cryptomator, ftp drives, etc) which incorporate some unstable dependency inside (usually network) without transactions or just using plain lazy-man solution with giant buffer in RAM (usefull for streaming services using ffmpeg or logs aggregation where losses are a common thing), but I dont think OP has any of those. It will probably throw error too, but has corner cases where operation is complete. As I said, system level guarantee, drivers on the other hand can be faulty.

Comment: @eocron Alright, so are there any measure we can take (maybe testing) that the file is ready for reading before we return? Make sense?

Comment: @Adrew If you are not using any of those, just write a small unit test. If you are using any of those, you will still not be able to take "measures" except banning custom drivers. Most people don't use them either or know what happens if they use them, so you are in safe zone.

Comment: @eocron Does it make sense to even single out those? What matters is that it's logically finished by the point where the respective C# code completes, and there is nothing you can do from C# to make it more complete. You don't even need to look at fancy storages, something as common as a hard drive cache is already enough to claim that it's not finished because it has not been actually persisted to disk. It is the job of the storage to correctly abstract it out (and give you correct contents back when you read it even it hasn't been "actually" persisted). You cannot do anything about it.

Comment: @GSerg Mentioned it for complete picture just because there is no C# in vacuum, from C# point of view its just a matter of correctly handling error rather than faulting critically.